# Use only one column in the script but also print another column of the same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas document with two columns. I try an LDA algorithm on the data in the second column and I print out the content of each topic. Everything works fine, and I have my output with the topic and its content (only the second column). But I wish my output with my topic and beyond the second column, the first one too.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation

n_components = 2
n_top_words = 5

def print_top_words(model, feature_names, n_top_words):
    out_list = []
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        message = "%d " % topic_idx #aqui que tem que mudar para consertar a saida
        message += " ".join([feature_names[i] for i in topic.argsort()[:-n_top_words - 1:-1]])

        out_list.append(message.split())
    return out_list

text = pandas.read_csv('listes.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
text_liste2 = text['liste2']
text_liste1 = text['liste1']
text_liste1_list = text_liste1.values.tolist()
text_liste2_list = text_liste2.values.tolist()

tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(text_liste2_list)
tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=n_components,     max_iter=5,learning_method='online',learning_offset=50.,random_state=0)

lda.fit(tf)

#print docs par topic - Funciona
document_topics = lda.fit_transform(tf)
topicos = print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)
for i in range(len(topicos)):
    print("Topic {}:".format(i))
    docs = np.argsort(document_topics[:, i])[::-1]
    for j in docs[:3]:
       print " ".join(text_liste2_list[j].encode('utf-8').split(",")[:2])
```

**Data**

```
liste1,liste2
'hello, how are you','hello'
'I am super intelligent','super intelligent'
'He is a great friend','great friend'
'THE book is on the table','book table'
'the EARTH is in danger','earth danger'
'I just can say goodbye','just goodbye' 
'she eats bananas','eats bananas'
'you say goodbye','say goodbye'
```

**My output:**

```
Topic 0:

book table
earth danger
just goodbye 
eats bananas

Topic 1:

hello
super intelligent
great friend
say goodbye
```

**Good output:**

```
Topic 0:
'THE book is on the table','book table'
'the EARTH is in danger','earth danger'
'I just can say goodbye','just goodbye' 
'she eats bananas','eats bananas

Topic 1:
'hello, how are you','hello'
'I am super intelligent','super intelligent'
'He is a great friend','great friend''
'you say goodbye','say goodbye'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, get rid of the the comma in the first row, in `Hello, how are you`.
Secondly, just print the `text_liste1_list[j]` in the last print :-) :

```
for j in docs[:3]:
   str2 = " ".join(text_liste2_list[j].encode('utf-8').split(",")[:2])
   print(text_liste1_list[j] + ',' + str2)
```